# Rolle's theorem without compact domain hypothesis

Tags: limits, rolles-theorem

Good evening everyone,
I'm asking for a proof of "Rolle's theorem generalization". The thesis is as follows:

Let be $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f:[a,\infty) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function such that $\lim_{{x\to \infty}} {f(x)} = f(a)$. Prove that if the derivative exists in $(a,\infty)$ then $\exists$  $x_0>a$ such that $f'(x)=0$.

I tried to prove that but I wasn't able to do it, so if you can help me I'll appreciate it a lot.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no point $x_0$ with $f'(x_0) = 0$, then either $f'(x) > 0$ or $f'(x)<0$ for all $x$. WLOG $f'(x) >0$, so the function is strictly increasing. Thus $f(a+1) > f(a)$, and $\forall x: x > a+1 \implies f(x) > f(a+1)$, so $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \ge f(a+1) > f(a)$, a contradiction.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I think it's correct! Thank you very much

Comment: @mcat You're welcome

Comment: Ovi.A question:You proved that f' >0 everywhere leads to a contradiction.Fine. One can conclude that f' \le 0 somewhere. If f'(x) =0, we are finished.If f'(x)<0 somewhere ,do we need, in addition, that f' is continuos, to conclude f'(x) somewhere in between?Thanks.

Comment: @Ovi Peter made me think about a thing: if $f'(x)$ is not continuous, your proof should be extended somehow, because then we can not tell if $f'(x)>0$ for ALL $x$ (the same for $<0$). It could be that $f'(x)$ has a jump discontinuity so it could not assume the value 0.

Comment: @mcat: Derivatives can't have jump discontinuities, but this a nontrivial fact ([Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we say the domain is $[a,+\infty],$ an interval closed at both ends, the a basic open neighborhood of $+\infty$ is any interval of the form $(b,+\infty],$ and we define $f(+\infty)$ to be $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x) = f(a).$ Then the extreme value theorem applies because topologically the domain $[a,+\infty]$ is the same as any closed bounded interval, and $f$ is continuous on that interval. So let $M= \max_x \left| f(x)\right|$ and we have some point $c\in(a,+\infty)$ for which $f(c) = M.$ Can you show $f'(c) \le 0$ and $f'(c)\ge 0$ by squeezing?

Comment: Not sure if I understood, but if I consider $[a,\infty]$ as a closed bounded interval, could I apply Rolle's theorem? Because in that case the thesis immediately follows. If I actually can not do that, in order to complete the proof I can apply Fermat's theorem: if $f$ admits maximum or minimum in $x_0$ then if the derivative exists in $x_0$ it will be 0. Not sure if that actually works, but this is what I thought. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @mcat : If you treat $[a,+\infty]$ as a closed bounded interval you can apply the extreme value theorem for the following reason: Suppose $f(a) = f(+\infty).$ Let $g(y) = a + f\left( \dfrac y {1-y}\right)$ for $0\le y\le 1,$ and when $y=1$ take the value of $y/(1-y)$ to be $\lim\limits_{y\,\uparrow\,1} \dfrac y{1-y}=+\infty.$ Then $g$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$ and so it assumes its extreme values. If $g$ assumes an extreme value at $c\in[0,1],$ then $f$ assumes an extreme value at the number $d\in[a,+\infty]$ for which $a + \dfrac d{1-d} =c.$ Then$\,\ldots$

Comment: $\ldots\,$having shown that $f$ assumes an extreme value, we have these possibilities: $f$ is constant (in which case the conclusion you want is trivial, or $f$ attains a maximum value that is${}>f(a)$ at some point $d\in(a,+\infty)$ (thus not at an endpoint) or $f$ attains a minimum value that is${}<f(a)$ at some point $d\in(a,+\infty)$ (thus not at an endpoint). Then work on showing that a maximum or a minimum that is not at an endpoint can occur only at a point where the derivative is $0.$ That last part is done by squeezing. $\qquad$

Comment: I.e. suppose $f(d) \ge f(x)$ for all $x\in[a,+\infty]$ and $a<d<+\infty.$ Then $$ \frac{f(d+h) -f(d)}{h} \left. \begin{cases} \le 0 & \text{if } h>0, \\ \ge 0 & \text{if } h <0. \end{cases} \right\} $$ Therefore $$f'(d) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(d+h) - f(d)} h \quad \begin{cases} \le 0 \\ \\ \text{and} \\ \\ \ge 0. \end{cases}$$

Comment: @mcat : TYPO!!!! I should have said $g(y) = f\left( a + \dfrac y{1-y} \right). \qquad$

Answer (score 0):

Define $g\colon [0,1/a]\to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
f(1/x) & x > 0\\
f(a) & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$

By your hypotheses, this function is continuous, and the derivative $g'(x)$ exists on $(0,1/a)$.  Specifically,
$$
g'(x) = -\frac{f'(1/x)}{x^2}\,,
$$
by the chain rule.

By Rolle's Theorem, we know that $g'(x)=0$ for some $x\in (0,1/a)$. It follows from the formula for $g'$ that $f'(1/x)=0$.